# FastQ programming error

Tags: python, fastq

So I'm trying to parse a FastQ sequence, but I'm a beginner to Python, and I'm a little confused as to why my code isn't working. This is what the program is supposed to carry out:

if I enter the FASTQ seqname line...

```
@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393
```

...then the program should output:

```
Instrument = EAS139
Run ID = 136
Flow Cell ID = FC706VJ
Flow Cell Lane = 2
Tile Number = 2104
X-coord = 15343
Y-coord = 197393
```

Here's my unfinished code thus far:

```
class fastq:
    def __init__(self,str):
        self.str = inStr.replace ('@',' ').split (':')
    def lists (self,parameters):
        self.parameters = ("Instrument","Run ID","Flow Cell ID","Flow Cell Lane","Tile     Number","X-coordinates","y-coordinates")
    def zip (self,myZip,zippedTuple):
        self.Zip = zip(self.parameters,self.transform)
        self.zippedTuple = tuple(myZip)
        print (tuple(myZip))

def main():
    seq = input('Enter FastQ sequence:')
    new_fastq = fastq(str)
    new_fastq.lists()
    new_fastq.zip()

main()
```

Comment: Having finished with the code, the question: you mention an error in the title, then *never say what it is*. You should *provide full traceback* for the error, as this helps people zero in on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code isn't working is that it's more-or-less entirely wrong. To address your errors in the order we reach them when trying to run the program:

1. `main`:

   1. `new_fastq = fastq(str)` does not pass the `seq` we just input, it passes the built-in string type;
2. `__init__`:

   1. Calling the argument to `fastq.__init__` `str` is a bad idea as it masks the very built-in we just tried to pass to it;
   2. But whatever you call it, be consistent between the function definition and what is inside it - where do you think `inStr` is coming from?
3. `lists`:

   1. Why is this separate to and not even called by `__init__`?
   2. Why don't you pass any arguments?
   3. What is the argument `parameters` even for?
4. `zip`:

   1. Rather than define a method to print the object, it is more Pythonic to define `fastq.__str__` that returns a string representation. Then you can `print(str(new_fastq))`. That being said;
   2. Again, you mask a built-in. On this occasion, it's more of a problem because you actually *try to use the built-in inside the method that masks it*. Call it something else;
   3. Again, you put unnecessary arguments in the definition, then don't bother to pass them anyway;
   4. What is `self.transform` supposed to be? It is never mentioned anywhere else. Do you mean `self.str` (which, again, should be called something else, for reasons of masking a built-in and *not actually being a string*)?
   5. `myZip` is one of the arguments you never passed, and I think you actually want `self.Zip`; but
   6. Why would you create `x = tuple(y)` then on the next line `print(tuple(y))`? `print(x)`!

Addressing those points, plus some bonus PEP-008 tidying:

```
class FastQ:

    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.elements = seq.replace ('@',' ').split (':')
        self.parameters = ("Instrument", "Run ID", "Flow Cell ID",
                           "Flow Cell Lane", "Tile Number",
                           "X-coordinates", "y-coordinates")

    def __str__(self):
        """A rough idea to get you started."""
        return "\n".join(map(str, zip(self.parameters, self.elements)))


def main():
    seq = input('Enter FastQ sequence: ')
    new_fastq = FastQ(seq)
    print(str(new_fastq))

main()
```